# Remove unwanted tags from clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I have a function which is successfully returning a ul list of random numbers between 1 and 100, and it places the numbers on the user's clipboard. This is just for IE but this isn't a problem.
This issue is that the resulting text on the clipboard is retaining the li tags like below. Is there a way to remove these tags from the data before it hits the clipboard?

```
<LI>68</LI>
<LI>97</LI>
<LI>94</LI>
<LI>43</LI>
<LI>45</LI>
<LI>65</LI>
```

The JS code:

```
function ReturnRandomNumbers() {    
    var howManyInt = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtMultiples").value);
    var listNumbers = document.getElementById("listNumbers");   
    var i = 0;      

    if (howManyInt < 101 && howManyInt > 0) {
        listNumbers.innerHTML = "";
        while (i < howManyInt) {
            AddItemToList(randomNumber());      
            i++;
        }       

        window.clipboardData.setData("text",listNumbers.innerHTML); 
        alert(listNumbers.innerHTML);
    } else {
        alert("Value must be between 1 and 100");
    }       
}


function AddItemToList(item) {
    var ol = document.getElementById("listNumbers");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    ol.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: its retaining tags because thats the way it is added in the list
AddItemToList is adding li tags, as you want to display it to user in form of list. And you are copying the innerHTML which gives you the text with tags

Comment: @avck but the clipboard doesn't care about tags or markup - it's just a string to the clipboard isn't it? therefore strings can be manipulated.......

Comment: yes it can be. before passing to the `setData` remove all the `li` tags if that is what you want

Comment: @avck but that is my question - how do you remove the li tags before reaching the clipboard?

Comment: regex match and replace, in the answer you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "<LI>68</LI>\n<LI>97</LI>\n<LI>94</LI>\n<LI>43</LI>\n<LI>45</LI>\n<LI>65</LI>"
```

or

```
var str = listNumbers.innerHTML;
```

You want to strip the `li` tags from the string, you can do a regex match and replace

```
var stripped =  str.replace(/<\/*LI>/g,'');
```

Which will give

> "68
>   97
>   94
>   43
>   45
>   65"

Pass it to your clipboard `window.clipboardData.setData("text",stripped);`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `ReturnRandomNumbers()` function into this:

```
function ReturnRandomNumbers()
{   
    var howManyInt = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtMultiples").value);
    var listNumbers = document.getElementById("listNumbers");   
    var i = 0;
    var strForClipboard = ''; 

if (howManyInt < 101 && howManyInt > 0) {
    listNumbers.innerHTML = "";
    while (i < howManyInt) {
        var randNumb = randomNumber();
        strForClipboard += (strClipboard ? '\n' : '') + randNumb;
        AddItemToList(randNumb);      
        i++;
    }       

    window.clipboardData.setData("text",strForClipboard); 
    alert(strForClipboard);
}
else {
        alert("Value must be between 1 and 100");
}       
}
```